# Contact Form reply address

Tags: php, email

When somebody send me a message on my websites contact form, I click the reply button to reply.

I then receive a response that the email was not delivered / failed.

Well, its because the gmail email wants to respond to the server email, instead of the email address that was entered into the Contact Form on my website.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Here is the PHP script for my contact form:

```
<?php
$mailTo = 'emailaddress@gmail.com';
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['cform_name']);
$mailFrom = htmlspecialchars($_POST['cform_email']);
$subject = 'Message from your website';
$message_text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['cform_message']);

$message =  'From: '.$name.'; Email: '.$mailFrom.' ; Message: '.$message_text;

mail($mailTo, $subject, $message);
?>
```

Comment: set the appropriate header, I'll let you look up which one that is

Comment: Dagon...I do not know PHP, but thanks for commenting anyways.

Comment: I amuse you know how to read the manual page.

Comment: Thank you again for another worthless comment. What manual page?

People come here with questions and answers, not to read crap you keep posting. If you do not want to answer then why bother wasting your time?

Comment: the php manual page for the function you are using -[mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) Example #2  to be specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
mail($mailTo, $subject, $message, 'Reply-To: '.$mailFrom);
```